# Authentication api twitter

Tags: javascript, api, backbone.js, twitter

by documentation (https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/application-only-auth) I need to implement an Ajax call to make an app only authentication. I've tried but twitter server respond me ever error 403 forbidden. Can anyone suggest me an Ajax implementation to do this?

Comment: you can check out this sample : https://github.com/TakahikoKawasaki/TwitterOAuthView

Comment: I'm sorry I need in javascript not in java

Comment: For best results, you'll need to post the code that you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make manually an Ajax call to request an authentication for Twitter is a bit complicate because Twitter needs some parameters in the request header. Plus this parameters needs to be encoded.
To resolve this problem I've found a good library: codebird.js.

Below code to make an authentication and use all twitter api.:

```
var cb = new Codebird;
cb.setConsumerKey("Yourkey","Yoursecret");
cb.setToken("Access token", "Access token secret");
```

Yourkey,Yoursecret,Access token,Access token secret are your personal number you can get by your twitter app management.